# Mongoose minor version change causes 'ObjectId' is not assignable to type 'Condition<string>'

Tags: mongoose

I am currently in `npm` dependency hell and the following error popped up after updating from `"mongoose": "^5.9.19"` to `"mongoose": "^5.13.16"`:

```
error TS2322: Type 'ObjectId' is not assignable to type 'Condition<string>'.
      Type 'ObjectId' is not assignable to type 'string'.

const settings = await this.settingsModel.findOne({ provider: device.provider }).exec();
```

I would like to find out what change in `mongoose` has caused this, but I can't find **detailed release notes**. the Slack channel invite doesn't work and the Google group forum is dead.

Do you have any advice how to diagnose this error? Here is someone with a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69412049/1097451), however my code used to work.